# Primefaces autocomplete: How to set focus on autocomplete after clicking on commandlink

Tags: primefaces

Scenario: I used  component and infront of autcomplete I used one command link with search image.

My purpose is to display cursor in autocomplete after clicking on commandlink.

My code is as follows:

**Autocomplete:**

```
<p:autoComplete id="senderAutocomplete" widgetVar="senderInfo"
                                                    value="#{customerReviewLazyDataModel.customerReviewVO.senderVO}"
                                                    completeMethod="#{customerReviewLazyDataModel.searchOrganizations}"
                                                    var="senderVO"  
                                                    itemValue="#{senderVO}" converter="organizationConverterForCustomerReview"
                                                    size="60">
```

**commandlink**

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="setFocus()" ajax="true">
                                                        <p:graphicImage value="/app-resources/themes/yob/images/search.png" style="margin-bottom: -4px;"></p:graphicImage>
                                                    </p:commandLink>
```

**js function**

```
function setFocus(){
        document.getElementById("senderAutocomplete").focus();
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID you are using to get the DOM-element for the input to focus is wrong. First of all you have to consider the id of the form. Additionally the id of the input of a `p:autoComplete` has a suffix `_input`. So use this:

```
document.getElementById("formId:senderAutocomplete_input").focus();
```

You should also set `process="@this"` on the `commandButton`, as you are just using it to focus the `autoComplete`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer solved my problem. I used 'document.getElementById("senderAutocomplete_input").focus();' this and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem adding a css style class and using jquery (which is included on Primefaces) to set the focus.

```
<p:autoComplete id="senderAutocomplete" widgetVar="senderInfo" ...

*styleClass="focusme"*
/>
```

And the commandlink would be like this:

```
<p:commandLink *oncomplete="$('.focusme').focus()"* ajax="true">
```